# swift SceneKit Sphere deformation after changing position

Tags: swift

I have two spheres on the `sceneView`

```
let earthSphere = SCNSphere(radius: 5.0)
earthSphere.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
let objNode1 = SCNNode(geometry: earthSphere)
objNode1.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)

let moonSphere = SCNSphere(radius: 0.5)
moonSphere.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
let objNode2 = SCNNode(geometry: moonSphere)
objNode2.position = SCNVector3(x: 3, y: 3, z: 0)
```

but `moonSphere` is deforming [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXMiY.jpg). How to fix that ? It is possible to do that `earthSphere` and `moonSphere` look same ? without deformation

etc: cameraNode set to position `SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 7)`

Comment: Isn't that how it's supposed to look when it's far away from the point of focus?

Comment: @ElTomato It is possible to do that earthSphere and moonSphere look same ? can add two point of focus ?